# Assuming 2O3 (g) → 3O2 (g), how much oxygen will be formed within 5.50 s for a reaction rate of 0.250 M/s?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, rate-equation

Context: The rate of appearance of $\ce{O2}$ in the reaction: $\ce{2O3 (g) -> 3O2 (g)}$ is $\pu{0.250 M/s}$. So, over the first $\pu{5.50 s}$, will it form $\pu{1.38 M}$, or $\pu{4.13 M}$ of oxygen during the given time?

Which is right? Here are my solutions:

1. $\pu{0.250 M/s} \cdot \pu{5.50 s} = \pu{1.38 M}$
2. $\pu{0.250 M/s} \cdot \pu{5.50 s} \cdot 3 = \pu{4.13 M}$,
   (3 in the calculation is the coefficient of the product in the reaction: $\ce{2 O3 (g) -> \mathbf{3} O2 (g)}$).

*I feel like the first one is right? I am overthinking this, and I need to make sure that I am doing this right.*

Comment: reaction_rate = abs(component_rate)/stoichiometric_coefficient

Comment: Note, *chemical* information may be advantageously formatted using on ChemSE with [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/). Take moment to familiarize with this. You are encouraged to use it in the body of questions, answers, and comments. Because it is something special not all web browsers understand well, *do not* use it in the title of questions or answers.

Comment: Hello, @Poutnik. Thank you for responding. May I ask what "abs" and "component_rate" refer? I am a bit confused since I have a different formula given by my instructor.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Buttonwood. I will use mhchem on my next posts.

Comment: abs is math function giving an absolute value. Component rate is the time derivative of the component(=reactant or product) concentration ( or partial pressure or total amount, depending on scenario). // Good practice is starting with symbolic algebraic formulas and keeping it this way until all formulas are ready to finally put there literal numbers.
It helps focusing on principles and improves orientation, spotting mistakes, the text reusability and its permanent value.